# How to compare 2 matrices and keep greatest values in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, comparison, max

I am using Matlab and  have 2 matrices:

```
A =

 0     0     1
 1     0     1
 1     1     0
```

and

```
B =

 0     0     1.1
 1.0   0     0.8
 1.2   0.8   0
```

My goal is to compare the 2 matrices and get the highest values of each i,j element and store such results into a third matrix C.
I am able to achieve such result by applying a for loop that checks every single element and then stores it into the matrix but i would like to have a more efficient and elegant way to do so. Can you suggest me some better way?

The result should be like:

```
C = 

 0     0   1.1
 1     0     1
 1.2   1     0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
C = max(A,B)
```

[Source on documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html#bupr915)